# How to verify genuine application's request to server

Tags: android, ios, web-services

We are running a mini game in our mobile money app.

The communication between the app and the backend server is traditional web service.

We detected that a lot of requests have been coming from a single user which we doubt has been simulating the request to the server.

How could we make sure that the request sent to the server is from a genuine app?

Thank you.

Comment: are you using SSL?

Answer (score 0):

If the spoofing request is actually worked our after reverse engineering (like network packet sniffing), you will have a hard time to detect.
I recommend adding extra encryption with private key and public key for minimal security especially you are dealing with money and private data.